# Getting OAuth tokens without user registration

Tags: meteor

I want to store multiple access/refresh token in a separate document, but without going through the built in OAuth workflow.

I have tried to manually make the request, but when I get redirected back to my application, the meteor oauth package 'highjacks' the route and it fails.

I also tried to reverse engineer the meteor oauth packages, but they're very confusing.

Any advice or highlevel/detailed plan on how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to set the OAuth redirect URI to whatever you want it to. With Google, when you set up a new Client ID, one of the fields is "Authorized redirect URIs".

[image: screen show of Create Client ID]

If you added the meteor-accounts package, remove it as that might interfere. The basic steps to do OAuth are:

- Create client credentials (client_id, client_secret) in the control panel for the OAuth provider. This will including setting up the redirect_uri
- Generate the login Url using the client_id, client_secret, and redirect_uri
- Implement the redirect_uri in your app to capture the auth code
- Exchange the auth code for an access token (and refresh token)
- If the access token expires, get a new access token using the refresh token

Here is a blog post with more detail:

http://blog.philcruz.com/2015/05/manually-getting-oauth-tokens-in-meteor.html

Here is an example project that manually uses OAuth:

https://github.com/philcruz/meteor-gmail-example